# Draw primitive 2D shapes on 3D models?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As far as I know, it is called projective texture mapping. Are there any library methods to project primitive 2D shapes (lines mostly) to a texture?

This threejs [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals) looks close to what I need. I tried replacing the decal texture (decalMaterial) with

```
THREE.LineBasicMaterial
```

but I get square instead of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a line onto a 3D texture is possible. But are you wanting that or just a decal on your model? There are other ways of putting a decal that might be better, but I'll assume you want to paint onto the texture. I've done it in Unity, but not WebGL and am not familiar with WebGL's limitations. It was a program that let's you paint onto 3D models like in Substance Painter, ZBrush, etc. I recommend doing this in a non-destructive manner at runtime so do this to a separate render texture then just combine the 2 textures for rendering in your final model.

To do this you are going to need to have to render your model into texture space. So in your vertex shader output the uv of the model as your position.

Been writing hlsl and Cg a lot recently so glsl is super rusty. Treat this more like psuedocode.

```
//Vertex Shader
in vec4 position;
in vec2 uv;

out vec4 fworldPos;
out vec2 fuv;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
   //We use the uv position of the model so we can draw into
   //its texture space.
   gl_Position = vec4(uv.x*2.0-1.0,uv.y*2.0-1.0,0.0,1.0);
   //Give the fragment shader the uv
   fuv = uv;
   //We will need to do per pixel collision detection with
   //the line or object so we need the world position.
   fworldPos = transform*position
}
```

You then need to do collision detection with your brush in the pixel shader and see if that world position is contained with your brush. Again though this is if you want to paint on it. Project I did we used raycasts onto the model so the brush would follow along the surface and do the above easily. This will give you a very rough looking brush and you'll need to add a lot of parameters to adjust how the brush looks like falloff strength, falloff radius, etc. Basically all the parameters you see in other painting 3D software.

You can do this with plane's, boxes, spheres, lines, whatever. Just need to test if the world position is contained within your brush. Will need different shaders for different types of brushes though.